# Integrals involving whittaker functions.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I want to compute the following integrals:

$$
\int y^{a} e^{\frac{1}{2}y}M_{k,m}(y)dy
$$
where a is an arbitrary constant and $M_{k,m}$ is a whittaker function of the first kind.

I already know that it is possible to compute cases when $a=m-\frac{1}{2},-m-\frac{1}{2}, m+\frac{1}{2}, -m+\frac{1}{2}, k,$or $-k$.

by using the derivatives of Whittaker functions.

My question is how to formulate when $a$ is a arbitrary constant. I know some relevant reference but i couldn't get that reference in my library and google.

Relevant references are :

A.Prudnikov et al. "Integrals Series: More special functions, vol. III of integrals and Series" pp 105--109.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5By%5Ea+WhittakerM%5Bk,+m,+y%5D+Exp%5By%2F2%5D,+y%5D) finds the result in terms of the Hypergeometric function ${}_p F_q$ with $p=q=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram alpha gives the result
$$\frac{2 y^{a+m+\frac{3}{2}} \, _2F_2\left(a+m+\frac{3}{2},-k+m+\frac{1}{2};a+m+\frac{5}{2},2 m+1;y\right)}{2 a+2 m+3}.$$

Comment: @user155214 Prudnikov vol. III formula 1.13.1.1 gives the same result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question related to the above fact. the hypergeometric function $_2F_2$ can be converted to the Whittaker functions?

Comment: @user155214: No, it is only the hypergeometric function $_1F_1$ that is equivalent to the Whittaker function.